# gdal_merge can't run (installation problem ?)

Tags: python, gdal

I need to merge several images into one big image.

I have downloaded GDAL from: [gisinternals](http://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1900-x64-gdal-2-4-0-mapserver-7-2-2.zip).
I also have installed this GDAL archive on my Windows 7:
`gdal-204-1900-x64-core.msi`

i have also downloaded and installed Python:
`python-3.7.2.exe`

I also set this in PATH env variable:

> C:\Users\firstname.name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32;C:\Program Files\GDAL;B:\PythonX\Lib\site-packages\osgeo;

If I use this command line:

```
gdal_merge.py -init 255 -o out.tif "C:\temp\image1.bmp" "C:\temp\image2.bmp"
```

I recieve this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
>   Files\GDAL\gdal_merge.py", line 38, in 
>       from osgeo import gdal ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo'

So for this, I have tried to install:
`GDAL-2.4.0.win-amd64-py3.7.msi`
and launched the command from the install folder it create and i have the same problem.

i am a beginner with GDAL and python.
how can i solve this problem ?
i do not find usefull solutions on the web.

*Note: i am under Windows 7.*

Thanks.

Comment: from the command line, enter `python`, then `from osgeo import gdal`. If that fails, you are missing something on the path (likely) or installation. If you make any changes remember to try in a new terminal window or python session for the changes to take effect.

Comment: if i use this command i have this error:
>>> from osgeo import gdal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo'

i suspect that something is not properly installed but i don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved my problem by installing GDAL from:
http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki

i have added these path to PATH:

```
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27;
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib;
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin;
```

And:

```
PYTHONHOME = C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27
PYTHONPATH = C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib
GDAL_DRIVER_PATH = C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdalplugins
```